# How to set remote drive path to chrome download path in my local system in selenium using JAVA

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

Can I set a remote drive folder as my local chrome download path using Selenium for Java? For normal local download path setting, I use

```
chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", "//Local Folder Path");
```

I'm unable to use the same for remote path setting, Can someone please help me with this?

**Ex:** My local drives (C:,D:,E:) , Remote drive (V:),

```
chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", "C:"); --> this is working fine.
chromePrefs.put("download.default_directory", "V:"); --> this is not working.
```

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Comment: @natn2323 using java.

Comment: @AndiCover ...Actually I'm trying to work on grid framework implementation, here while opening the remote browser for actions, I need to set remote drive path as my chrome download path.

Comment: Are you able to access the remote drive using *any* script? That is, see if you can even access it outside of using Selenium